# Eclipse не добавляет appcompat при создании проекта

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

Такая проблема. При создании приложения Eclipse не добавляет appcompat. И из-за этого ошибки в приложении. Все установил, AVD, jdk , плагин для еклипс.
В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Покажите app/build.gradle

Comment: @Соколов а как его найти не подскажете? я не силен в андройд разработке...

Comment: Users/<папка_пользователя>/AndroidStudioProjects/<название_приложения>/app/build.gradle. P.S. Это у меня, в AndroidStudio.

Comment: @Соколов нет такого файлика в приложении созданного через eclipse

Comment: Я бы посоветовал отказаться от использования Eclipse при разработке android-приложений, так как ADT уже давно не поддерживается.

Comment: @post_zeew мне нужно не большое приложение сделать. с eclipse опыт уже есть. на новый ноут не могу установить))